# How to structure tests for processes that occur over time?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

What is the approach for constructing tests of code that don't have an outcome in the immediate sense?

Let's say we have a very simple (yet quite rude) process:

- User signs up to site
- Two days pass

  - Send reminder email
  - Update some database fields
- Ten days pass

  - Send "c'ya" email
  - Delete account

I can write tests for each set of sub tasks (email is sent, database is updated, etc). However how do I write well structured tests, that read something like:

"Two days after registration, reminder email should be sent"
"Ten days after registration, account is deleted"

Although I am using PHP and PHPUnit, I feel the question may/may not be language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on implementation of your event mechanics. Like, when some event listener somewhere in your code receives event `user:reminder` with user id, then you need just:

1) Test reminder-send script by sending that event manually:

```
$eventBus->init();
$eventBus->attachListener($reminderListener);

$eventBus->fire(new ReminderEvent($user->id));

$this->expect(...); // reminder must be `sent`
```

2) Test generation of event when time had passed:

```
$time = now();
$delay = ...;

$emitter = new RemindEventEmitter($user->id, $time + $delay)

$eventBus->addEmitter($emitter);

$eventBus->setCurrentTime($time); // when we just registered emitter...
$eventBus->run();

$this->expectNot(...); // ... that event _must not_ be fired

$eventBus->setCurrentTime($time + $delay); // manually skip $delay time ...
$eventBus->run();

$this->expect(...); // test that event _must_ be fired
```

And that event-spawning/dispatching thing (`$eventBus` in my example) must relay on mockable/replacable time-getter:

```
// in production code
$eventBus->setCurrentTime(now());

// elsewhere in tests
$eventBus->setCurrentTime(<point in time you want to test against>);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I am using Laravel/PHPUnit, and Laravel uses Carbon to handle dates - your answer led me to find the following snippet from Carbon: `Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::now()->addDay(3));`